# next.config.js rewrites not working on S3 but work locally

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, next.js

I am having some weird behavior with my rewrites on S3 vs hosting locally.

My `next.config.js`

```js
module.exports = withImages({
  async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: '/dashboard/:any*',
        destination: '/admin/app',
      },
      {
        source: '/env/:any*',
        destination: '/admin/app',
      },
      {
        source: '/app/:any*',
        destination: '/admin/app',
      }
    ]
  }
});
```

I merely uploaded the `out/` folder to S3. My bucket static hosting config:

[image: S3 bucket config]

Locally, when I run `next build` and `next start` I see the redirects working as expected. However, when deployed to S3 only the `/dashboard/:any*` redirect seems to work. Any idea why that would happen?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Did you ever get this working? I'm trying to export a static Next.js app and only host via a CDN with no server component while allowing dynamic paths.

Comment: @ChadJohnson Sort of. My use case for the rewrites was to move to a dynamic path that was handle by React Router. So for S3 what I did was set the error document to a Next.js page with my React Router routes, and that solved the problem. Any pages that already exist S3 can handle because they match the URL

Answer (score 1):

A S3 bucket is only suitable to host a static website, however you are using `next start` which starts a local server that can resolve dynamic routes.

Instead you need to run `next export` after `next build`, then use a tool like [`serve`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve) to statically serve your out folder:

```
serve out
```

This will be very close to what S3 is doing, and it will be easier to test that your webapp works before the deployment.

I am not familiar with this `withImages` function, so I don't know whether this is supposed to work out of the box with `next export` or not. If not you might have to play with `exportPathMap` - have a look to [next documentation for static export](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/static-html-export).